# Failed Error Handling for Selection of Grouped Shapes Array

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I have a selection of code below that is supposed to construct the name of a line connecting two groups of shapes. The group names sit in column A. Based on criteria in column C, the code changes the formatting of certain lines.

My issue is that I keep getting a "Run-time error '1004': The item with the specified name wasn't found on the line:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(targetLine1)).Select
```

The group name for targetLine1 may not exist for a particular set of criteria, but I don't understand why the error is not being handled. I tried using both On Error and If IsError to deal with this problem, and neither have been able to handle the errors.

```
Sub SHOW_SINGLE_CONNECTIONS()

    Dim targetRow As Integer
    Dim targetRow2 As Integer
    Dim targetCell2 As String
    Dim targetCell3 As String

    Dim targetLine1 As String
    Dim targetLine2 As String

    targetRow = 2
    targetRow2 = 2

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & targetRow))
        targetCell2 = "A" & targetRow

        If (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & targetRow)) = "True" Then

            Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & targetRow2))
                targetCell3 = "A" & targetRow2

                If targetCell3 = targetCell2 Then
                    GoTo Spot1
                ElseIf (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & targetRow2)) = "False" Then
                    GoTo Spot1
                End If

                targetLine1 = ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value
                targetLine1 = Left(targetLine1, 32)
                targetLine2 = ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value
                targetLine2 = Left(targetLine2, 32)

                On Error GoTo Spot2
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(targetLine1)).Select
                With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .Transparency = 0
                End With

                Spot2:

                On Error GoTo Spot3
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(targetLine2)).Select
                With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .Transparency = 0
                End With

                Spot1:
                Spot3:

                targetRow2 = targetRow2 + 1

            Loop

        End If

        targetRow = targetRow + 1

    Loop
End Sub
```

Per first response:

```
Private Sub TryFormatShape(targetLine As String)

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(targetLine)).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
End With
Err.Clear
End Sub

Sub SHOW_SINGLE_CONNECTIONS()

Dim targetRow As Integer
Dim targetRow2 As Integer
Dim targetCell2 As String
Dim targetCell3 As String

Dim targetLine1 As String
Dim targetLine2 As String

targetRow = 2
targetRow2 = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & targetRow))
    targetCell2 = "A" & targetRow

    If (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & targetRow)) = "True" Then

        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & targetRow2))
            targetCell3 = "A" & targetRow2

            If targetCell3 <> targetCell2 And (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & targetRow2)) = "True" Then

            MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value
            MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value

            targetLine1 = ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value
            targetLine1 = Left(targetLine1, 32)
            targetLine2 = ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value
            targetLine2 = Left(targetLine2, 32)

            TryFormatShape targetLine1
            TryFormatShape targetLine2

            targetRow2 = targetRow2 + 1

            End If

        Loop

    End If

    targetRow = targetRow + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Now when I run the code Excel freezes up, and I have to break it to escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error handler isn't being reset before the code runs through the loop again.  I'd actually get rid of all of the `GoTo` statements and extract a `Sub` out for the common functionality:

```
Private Sub TryFormatShape(targetLine As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(targetLine)).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

That lets you isolate the error handling into context of the new routine instead of looping through it.  It also lets you simplify your main loop to something more like this:

```
        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & targetRow2))
            targetCell3 = "A" & targetRow2

            If targetCell3 <> targetCell2 And (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & targetRow2)) <> "False" Then
                targetLine1 = ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value
                targetLine1 = Left(targetLine1, 32)
                targetLine2 = ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value
                targetLine2 = Left(targetLine2, 32)

                TryFormatShape targetLine1
                TryFormatShape targetLine2
            End If
            targetRow2 = targetRow2 + 1
        Loop
```

Comment: Also, when I run into issues involving shape/object names, I often write a test loop to `Debug.Print` a list of all the names of all the objects, just to verify that my constructed name actually matches an existing name. Sometimes I've had to add an `If` statement to that test loop to verify the comparison is working (just in case there are discrepancies with an extra space or non-printable characters).

Comment: @PeterT - Agreed.  The root of the issue is likely "the group name for targetLine1 may not exist for a particular set of criteria", but the OP doesn't give any information that would facilitate refactoring in a way that resolves that.

Comment: Now when I run the code it freezes up Excel, and I have to break it to get out.

Comment: @Comintern Only 27, I wouldn

Comment: @Comintern Only 27, I wouldn't think it would be that heavy.

Comment: @MattDixon - Oops.  The `targetRow2 = targetRow2 + 1` needs to go outside of the `If` statement.  See the edit.

Comment: @Comintern Thanks, I just realized that after applying some message boxes to track the changing rows. I am re-testing now.

Comment: @Comintern Awesome, it works as expected. I appreciate it. I up-voted, but my reputation is still so low that I am not sure if it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Comintern's answer:

```
Private Sub TryFormatShape(targetLine As String)

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(targetLine)).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
End With
Err.Clear
End Sub



Sub SHOW_SINGLE_CONNECTIONS()

Dim targetRow As Integer
Dim targetRow2 As Integer
Dim targetCell2 As String
Dim targetCell3 As String

Dim targetLine1 As String
Dim targetLine2 As String

targetRow = 2
targetRow2 = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & targetRow))
    targetCell2 = "A" & targetRow

    If (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & targetRow)) = "True" Then

        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & targetRow2))
            targetCell3 = "A" & targetRow2

            If targetCell3 <> targetCell2 And (ActiveSheet.Range("C" & targetRow2)) = "True" Then

            MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value
            MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value

            targetLine1 = ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value
            targetLine1 = Left(targetLine1, 32)
            targetLine2 = ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell2).Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range(targetCell3).Value
            targetLine2 = Left(targetLine2, 32)

            TryFormatShape targetLine1
            TryFormatShape targetLine2

            End If

            targetRow2 = targetRow2 + 1

        Loop

    End If

    targetRow = targetRow + 1

Loop

End Sub
```